# Is there a way to create a list of Vocabulary (Replicate this page: /admin/structure/taxonomy)

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have created a custom layout and in that i want to show the content of this page -> `/admin/structure/taxonomy`.

Please suggest if there is any way out.

Thanks

Comment: You could use Views. Or a custom back end theme. Go for Views.

Comment: In views i couldn't find a way to show vocabulary listing. I could only list terms.

Answer (score 1):

See the docs on how to [Create a custom page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/create-a-custom-page) which calls a controller.

In the callback method put `$vocabularies = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_vocabulary')->loadMultiple();` to get all vocabularies.

Then use a `foreach` construct to add all vocabulary labels to a render array, for example an item list.

```
$items = [];
/** @var \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Vocabulary[] $vocabularies */
$vocabularies = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_vocabulary')->loadMultiple();
foreach ($vocabularies as $vocabulary) {
  $items[] = $vocabulary->label();
}
$content = [
  '#theme' => 'item_list',
  '#list_type' => 'ul',
  '#title' => 'My List',
  '#items' => $items,
  '#attributes' => ['class' => 'mylist'],
  '#wrapper_attributes' => ['class' => 'container'],
];
```